# PHP8.1-fpm: pdo-mysql installed but not appear on php -m

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, php-8.1

i have install **php8.1-fpm** and setup it with **apache2/FGPI**. But after many operation, impossible to "*enable pdo-mysql*".

i have make this `sudo apt-get install php8.1-pdo-mysql`

with result

```
Note, selecting 'php8.1-mysql' instead of 'php8.1-pdo-mysql'
php8.1-mysql is already the newest version (8.1.5-1+b1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded
```

But, when i do `php -m`

mysql not appear.

```
[PHP Modules]
Core
curl
date
dom
filter
gd
gmp
hash
igbinary
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
OAuth
openssl
pcntl
pcre
redis
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sodium
SPL
standard
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
yaml
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Xdebug
```

When i try to know why, it seem because Pdo is include on php8.1-common, but ... not appear to.

An other action that i have doing is to remove php8.1-mysql and reinstall php8.11-pdo-mysql with `sudo apt-get install php8.1-pdo-mysql`, the result is[image: Result of apt-get install]

but, nothing on `mods-available`

[image: mods-available]

**EDIT 1**
When i look with phpinfo() on a php file to use
php-fpm, i have this result

```
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/15-xml.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-curl.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-dom.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-gd.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-gmp.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-imap.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-intl.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-oauth.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-redis.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,     
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-xsl.ini,         
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-yaml.ini, 
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/20-zip.ini
```

**EDIT2**
When i use `php8.1-mysql` instead of `php8.1-pdo-mysql` same result because apt automaticly switch on php8.1-mysql when you try to install pdo-mysql.

**EDIT3**
The command `sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql` take the result

```
WARNING: Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
WARNING: Module pdo_mysql ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/8.1/mods-available
```

This is the real problem, that the needed file never been created by `sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql`

Comment: `Note: selecting 'php8.1-mysql' instead of 'php8.1-pdo-mysql'`

Comment: But  php -m has nothing to do with **php8.1-fpm**. Why you're checking console php instead of php-fpm?

Comment: I have the same result on both. For phpinfo(), that use php8.1-fpm, i have the same result in other form

Comment: The logs tell you how to enable FPM and where to create the INI file; then `sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql` enables the module... just needs to be added to mods available.

Comment: This dont work. I edit my post with the result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thx for your comment. I have find the solution in an other post :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64661113/19034672

I have doing the `--purge` of all php installed, and reinstall php-fpm, and all is done.