# I got this problem while running ./yii2 serve : - Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: php, yii2

I got this problem while running ./yii2 serve : - Unable to load dynamic library

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20210902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: pdo_parse_params)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Did you check if that directory actually exists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo\_mysql.so'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62240102/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-pdo-mysql-so)